# C# how to override function with parameter

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

```
public class Arrow : MonoBehaviour {

    public virtual void StopArrow(Transform p){
        arrowRotation = transform.rotation;
        isRelease = false;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        transform.SetParent(p);
        transform.rotation = arrowRotation;
    }
}

public class ExplosiveArrow : Arrow {
    override void StopArrow(Transform p){
        base.StopArrow();
    }
}
```

This gives me this error:

> Assets/Script/ExplosiveArrow.cs(33,23):  error CS0621:
>   `ExplosiveArrow.StopArrow(Transform)': virtual or abstract members
>   cannot be private

and

> Assets/Script/ExplosiveArrow.cs(33,23): error CS0507:
>   `ExplosiveArrow.StopArrow(UnityEngine.Transform)`: cannot change
>   access modifiers when overriding `public` inherited member
>   `Arrow.StopArrow(UnityEngine.Transform)`

Comment: the error says it all - change `override void StopArrow` to `public override void StopArrow`

Answer (score 2):

Change `override void StopArrow(Transform p){` to `public override void StopArrow(Transform p){` in your child class and you're done.

Unlike C++, you can't change the access of an overridden method to `private` if it's marked as `public` in a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

In C# if you don't declare the access modifiers of the variables and methods in your class, by default they are going to be `private`.

According [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers):

> The access level for class members and struct members, including
>   nested classes and structs, is private by default.

So as you can see in your code, `Arrow` has a `public virtual void StopArrow` but `ExplosiveArrow` has a `override void StopArrow` which by default is the same as `private override void StopArrow`.

So, if you declare an element as `public` in a parent class, then you cannot reduce the visibility of that variable/method. If you don't want to  expose an element but still you want to be able to access in derived classes you should use `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

## Also...

Assuming only the code you posted, this `base.StopArrow();` will also error.

> StopArrow() doesn't exist in base class Arrow

You need `base.StopArrow(p);` there instead.